# add attributes dynamically to the html element based on Index value in the element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Scenario:

if fileupload index value is 0 then it has to find fileindex=0 in the fullHTML and add some more attributes dynamically. like image-type = "png", image-timestamp="Wed Jul 22 13:48:30 EDT 2020"

```
fileupload.forEach(function (item, index) { 

var fullHtml = "<div id="comments-box" contenteditable="true" data-text="Enter comment">

    <a class="test-image test-upload" contenteditable="false" fileindex="0"
        image-title="great_life5.jpg" href="#" target="_blank">
        <span>great_life5.jpg</span></a>

    <a class="test-image test-upload" contenteditable="false" fileindex="1"
    image-title="greatlife_updated.png" href="#" target="_blank">
        <span>greatlife_updated.png</span></a>
</div>"

})


expected output: 

var fullHtml = "<div id="comments-box" contenteditable="true" data-text="Enter comment">

    <a class="test-image test-upload" image-id="39833" data-type="reviewImage" image-title="great_life5.jpg"
        image-timestamp="Wed Jul 22 13:48:30 EDT 2020" image-type="png" contenteditable="false" href="#"
        target="_blank"> great_life5.jpg</a>

    <a class="test-image test-upload" image-id="39834" data-type="reviewImage" image-title="greatlife_updated.png"
        image-timestamp="Wed Jul 22 13:48:30 EDT 2020" image-type="png" contenteditable="false" href="#"
        target="_blank">greatlife_updated.png</a>
</div>"
```

Comment: `fileupload.forEach(function (item, index)` {  what does this function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can acheive this by creating a dom element which hold your html and request on it with the dom api which is cleaner and easier than parsing it like text

```js
var fullHtml = `<div id="comments-box" contenteditable="true" data-text="Enter comment">

    <a class="test-image test-upload" contenteditable="false" fileindex="0"
        image-title="great_life5.jpg" href="#" target="_blank">
        <span>great_life5.jpg</span></a>

    <a class="test-image test-upload" contenteditable="false" fileindex="1"
    image-title="greatlife_updated.png" href="#" target="_blank">
        <span>greatlife_updated.png</span></a>
</div>`

const container = document.createElement("div")
container.innerHTML = fullHtml;
[1,2].forEach((item, index) => {
  let e = container.querySelector(`a[fileindex='${index}']`)
  e.setAttribute('yourAttribute', 'yourValue');
  e.setAttribute('image-timestamp', new Date().toString())
})

console.log(container.innerHTML)
```

Comment: let e = container.querySelector(`a[fileindex='${index}']`) backtick `  template literal is throwing error in IE . is there any alternative method for the same func

Comment: The alternative is let e = container.querySelector("a[fileindex='"+index+"']")